# Replace java class variable from gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I would like to have a gradle task replace a variable in a java class.  This is the java class I want to manipulate:

```
package com.me.test;

public class Config {
    public static final String FLAG = "variable";
}
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

...

task specialJar(type: Jar) {
   ...

   // Can I replace Config.FLAG in here somehow?
   // Something like:
   com.me.test.Config.FLAG = "foo";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Replacing it in the jar task is way too late. You would need to replace it in the source code, before the compilation happens. But why do that? Why not read that variable from some external file or resource instead?

Comment: @JBNizet I need to have it compiled into the jar for distribution to different customers, for example. The jar won't be able to read from a file system etc at runtime. I think that's what you're suggesting? Or do you mean read from a file during compilation time via gradle?

Comment: I mean putting a properties file, containing that value, inside the jar file, and reading it from the embedded properties file at runtime. Properties files are trivial to filter during the gradle build. Reading a properties file embedded in the jar doesn't need any access to the file system.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense - can you add that as an answer so I can accept?